# How to insert variables into Java code from a GUI textbox/submit?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

This is my first Java project and I'm not sure where to look/what to search for for information on this question.

I've built Java code in Eclipse using Selenium WebDriver that opens a product page, adds a product to cart, and completes the checkout process automatically. Is it possible to create a GUI with textbox submissions that would insert variables into my already-created code? For example, I'd like to create a GUI that would update my code with the submitted size rather than having to hard-code '6.5' every time as seen in the code below.

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='size-options-buttons']/ul//a[@title='6.5']")).click();
```

Any information or guidance on what to research would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't think you would want/need to create a GUI to do this. You should just create a variable that contains the value you want used in your searches and then you can update that value any time you want in only one place.

```
String title = "6.5";
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='size-options-buttons']/ul//a[@title='" + title + "']")).click();
```

If you wanted, you could read this and other values from a text file, XML, etc.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable with Java, but its not a part of Selenium as such. You can explore Java GUI frameworks such as AWT, Swing etc, using which you can create your GUI. You can add a text box and button in your UI. Upon click of the button, you can run your Selenium code, where it can fetch the value you entered in the text box as a variable as pass it on to your script.

It all depends on how far you want to take this. You can create very basic UIs with say JavaScript, VBScript as well. These would give you the basic functionality of a text box and button.

You can use an excel sheet also, where you can set these values and pass it on to your script.